# ArcMap "Could not load data from the data source" Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, arcgis-10.4, osmosis

I used ArcMap 10.4.1 to connect to a postgre SQL database generated by osmosis on a server. I could see the feature rendering (e.g., points and lines) without a problem. However, when I tried to examine the attribute tables, some could be displayed while the others couldn't. For those tables that couldn't be loaded in ArcMap, I received the following error message:

[image]

However, in ArcCatalog, all tables can be viewed except this one:

[image]
[image]

Table Schema

[image]

Error Message in ArcCatalog

What could be the possible causes of this error?

Comment: Well, a bad network connection *could* cause the issue, but use of unsupported datatype(s) in one or more fields would be my first guess.  Please edit the question to contain the SQL definition of one of the tables that generates this error. Use of a BIGINT field is the highest probability, but there are other unsupported types as well.

Comment: @Vince The question has been updated since I could view the tables in ArcCatalog but not ArcMap...

Comment: Please update the question to contain the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement used to create the table (pgAdminII will show this).  Knowing how Catalog sees the columns doesn't really help, unless the base table SQL is available.  I'm gessing `id` *and* `changeset_id` are `bigint`, and therefore not supported.

Comment: @Vince You are right, `id` and `changeset_id` are `bigint` in Table `Nodes`, however, I can view another table `Ways` with exact same schema definition in ArcCatalog. Both tables cannot be viewed in ArcMap, only the geometry can be displayed.